# ¿Hay que usar el indicativo o el subjuntivo cuando "Quizás" o "Tal vez" están en fin de una oración?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

Ya sé que "Tal vez" y "Quizá(s)" pueden generar tanto el indicativo como el subjuntivo cuando se encuentran antes del verbo. Pero si un hablante no está seguro de lo que habla y quiere ponerlas en fin de una oración, ¿el verbo el que se encuentra antes de estas palabras estaría en el subjuntivo o el indicativo?

Por ejemplo, en esta oración está claro:

"*Quizás algún día tengas hijos*" (también se puede decir "*Quizás algún día tendrás hijos*" si un hablante está seguro de esto)

Pero "*Algún día tengas hijos, quizás*." - ¿Se puede decir de esta manera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los adverbios que expresan duda, como *quizás, tal vez, probablemente, posiblemente*, pueden efectivamente combinarse con indicativo o subjuntivo cuando aparecen antes del verbo (no necesariamente al inicio de la oración). El subjuntivo expresa mayor duda que el indicativo.

Cuando los adverbios mencionados aparecen después del verbo, sólo se puede usar indicativo y su uso tiene un valor reformulatorio, como si el hablante decidiera echar un manto de duda luego de haber hecho una aseveración.

- Algún día **quizás tengas / tendrás** hijos.
- Algún día **tal vez tengas / tendrás** hijos.
- Algún día **probablemente/posiblemente tengas / tendrás** hijos.

Pero:

- Algun día **tendrás** hijos, **quizás**.
- Algun día **tendrás** hijos, **tal vez**.
- Algun día **tendrás** hijos, **probablemente/posiblemente**.

La imposibilidad de usar subjuntivo en los últimos casos se debe a la ausencia de una estructura previa que imponga el uso de ese modo verbal, como *Espero que tengas hijos, Ojalá tengas hijos, Me gustaría que tengas hijos, Es necesario que tengas hijos*, etc.

Al carecer de ese tipo de estructuras precedentes que obligan al uso del subjuntivo, la oración requiere modo indicativo.

Para completar mi respuesta a partir de los comentarios suscitados, a diferencia de los adverbios mencionados, que pueden agregarse después de una coma al final de la oración, en los demás casos habría que colocar un punto, o en algún caso dos puntos. También podrían usarse paréntesis (creo que también una raya):

- Algun día **tendrás** hijos. **Espero**.
- Algun día **tendrás** hijos (**espero**).
- Algun día **tendrás** hijos - **espero**.
- Algun día **tendrás** hijos. **Ojalá**.
- Algun día **tendrás** hijos. **Me gustaría**.
- Algun día **tendrás** hijos. **Es necesario**.
- Algun día **tendrás** hijos: **es necesario**.

Cabe destacar que estas oraciones finales no son usuales y pueden sonar extrañas: no es habitual que el hablante vuelva sobre sus pasos en oraciones tan breves, y es más común que plantee la duda, el deseo o la necesidad desde el principio.

Comment: ¿Esto es solo con los adverbios que expresan duda que solo se puede usar indicativo con un valor reformulatorio cuando aparecen después del verbo? ¿O es posible con todas palabras que imponerían el uso de subjuntivo en una situación estandar (antes del verbo)? Si lo entiendo correcto, esto aplica a todas palabras debido a "la ausencia de una estructura previa que imponga el uso de ese modo verbal". Por ejemplo, en esta oración solo se puede decir así: "Algún día tendrás hijos, ojalá/es necesario!" y no es posible usar "Tengas". ¿Puedes confirmarlo, por favor?

Comment: Muy interesante respuesta. No me había planteado esta diferencia de usos. @Alex, efectivamente, con "ojalá" pasa lo mismo que con "quizá" y otros adverbios, pero no con las estructuras verbales como "Me gustaría".

Comment: @pablodf76 ¿Y qué pasa con las estructuras verbales como "Me gustaría"? ¿Es que no es común ponerlas en fin de una oración? Y por eso supongo que sería correcto escribir así: "Algún día tendrás hijos. Me lo gustaría/Es necesario." ¿Lo entiendo correctamente?

Comment: @Alex Respondí tu duda haciendo un agregado a mi respuesta.

Comment: @Gustavson Yo pensaba en cosas como "Que algún día tengas hijos me gustaría". También funciona con predicados adjetivos ("es necesario"). No se puede hacer con "espero" sin sonar muy extraño.